# Problems printing a subclass and having access to its information properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, subclass

There is this superclass here:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, desc, usable, value):
        self.name = name
        self.desc = desc
        self.usable = usable
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}\n=====\n{}\nValue: {}\n".format(self.name, self.desc, self.usable, self.value)
```

And this subclass (among others):

```
class HPot(Item):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(desc="Heals for 5 HP.",
                         name="Health Potion",
                         usable=0,
                         value=3)

IHpot = HPot
```

And it's in a list called `Inv`:

```
Inv = [IHpot]
```

And when I `print(Inv)`, this occurs, obviously:

```
[<class 'items.HPot'>]
```

So I made this code:

```
def openinv():
    print("Your inventory:")
    print(', '.join(Inv))
    print("----------")
    # [...]
```

And then this happens:

```
Your inventory:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Bernardo/PycharmProjects/EndlessDungeon/inventory.py", line 
29, in <module>
    openinv()
  File "C:/Users/Bernardo/PycharmProjects/EndlessDungeon/inventory.py", line 18, in openinv
    print(', '.join(Inv))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, type found

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I thought that `return "{}\n=====\n{}\nValue: {}\n".format(self.name, self.desc, self.usable, self.value)` would help (it's there in the `Item` superclass), but nothing that I tried or searched online helped me. I want to print it like `Health Potion`, and still be able to have access to the class' `name, desc, usable,` etc. How could I do this?

Comment: Are you trying to print the class itself, or an instance of the class?

Comment: I'm not very good at thess terms, but I think what I want is to print the class itself. Like, print the .name of the class, while having access to .usable, .value and so on.

Comment: These are not attributes of the class, they do not exist in the class. They are attributes of the instances of the class.

Comment: Note that your problem has absolutely nothing to do with subclassing.

Comment: @Elazar Since he didn't know what his problem was, he didn't know that either.

Comment: @PaulCornelius I've added that comment after you posted your answer, so now the OP knows :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inventory contains the classes, but it looks like you want it to contain instances of those classes.

Instead of:

```
IHPot = HPot
```

Do:

```
IHPot = HPot()
```

And then for `openinv` you can turn each of the `Item` instances into `str`s like this:

```
def openinv():
    print("Your inventory:")
    print(', '.join([str(i) for i in Inv]))
    print("----------")
```

You have to instantiate the `Item` class before you can use the instance methods (the methods where the first parameter is `self`). Search for "python class vs instance methods" if you want more information.

Answer (score 2):

You never created an *instance* of the subclass `Hpot`.  In Python everything is an object, including classes.  So when you write the line

```
IHpot = HPot
```

you don't create an instance of HPot, you create a second name for the class itself.

To create an instance you need to call the class as if it were a function.

```
IHpot = HPot()
```

This line of code creates an instance of HPot, which has all those attributes you spoke about.

You have a second problem as well.  IHpot has a `__str__` method, but it is not a str.  The join function expects a list of strings, not a list of objects that can be converted to a string.  You must convert the list yourself, for example with a list comprehension:

```
InvAsStrings = [str(a) for a in Inv]
```

Comment: +1. I think it's important to note here the strong convention to use CamelCase (such as `HPot`) only for class names, and `snake_case` for other variables. It will help to avoid confusion.